# Page footer bounces up and down in view as content changes from jQuery DOM manipulations (add/remove/etc)

Tags: jquery, html, css

My page generates a lot of information dynamically and uses jQuery to add/remove show/hide stuff in the DOM.

This causes the page footer to bounce up and down in the visible area of the screen as the page empties and loads new content.

```
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <div id="content"/>
        <div id="footer"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ideally the page footer would never be visible to the user without scrolling down because the footer is distracting information that the user doesn't neeed to see unless he or she is looking for it.

Should I position the footer dynamically with jQuery?

Something like this?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#footer").css('top', $(window).height() + 20);
});
```

Comment: why are you resizing footer on window resize???

Comment: are you interested in fixing the issue???

Comment: @gov - he is not resizing the footer, it is moving with the expanding/contracting content.

Answer (score 1):

Other options:

Hide the footer, replace the content, then show the footer again.

Set the height of the content, replace it, then remove the height.

Comment: I personally like the effect of the first option here, but it seems like the second option is what you are looking for.  Setting the height of the content will prevent any bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options here:

1. Try to absolutely position the footer at the bottom of the screen. This is not as easy at it sounds. It depends upon the screen size. You will need to dynamically position this element (which will need to be absolutely positioned).
2. Try to minimize the bouncing. For instance, if you knew that generally the dynamic content height is less than 400px you could set the CSS 'min-height' style to 400px.

The first method seems overly complex. My recommendation would be to do the second.

Hope this helps.

Bob